# New Token Contract Disappears After Deployment

Tags: contract-deployment, tokens

I'm attempting to deploy my version of the example token contract to the testnet.

**This is how far I get:**

- The code compiles
- The contract doesn't complain pre-deloyment
- I see the contract deployment process appear in the Latest Transactions panel

**These are the issues I'm seeing:**

- The contract deployment process doesn't make any progress
- After about 1-2 minutes, the contract disappears entirely
- My account does not get charged for the deployment

**Other info:**

- On the first attempt I sent 2 ETH to the contract, and it failed. Now if I attempt to send any ETH to a new contract I see "It seems this transaction will fail..."
- Now only sending 0 ETH apart from the fee will remove that warning

I've got Ethereum Wallet v0.8.9 and Geth v1.5.8-stable

What am I doing wrong?